# How I fixed a broken spring in an extension ladder rung lock

Tags: ladder

I found many people have this issue with older ladders.  The biggest issue is older ladders use quite a different rung lock, so there's no replacement parts.  The spring on my ladder is a coil spring, kind of like ones found in clocks.  The end of the spring is folded over to make a clip that attaches to the side of the spring enclosure.  The first pic shows this (the red line indicates where the clip broke on the other one).
[image]
What I did to fix this is to use those fasteners you find on cars--called a spring nut.  I clipped that over the remaining piece of the clip and that secured it to the side of the spring enclosure (see second pic).  The spring nut is slim enough so it doesn't impede the functioning of the rung lock.
[image]

Comment: Interesting,  but it is not a question. Perhaps there is an unanswered  question of *how to fix a ladder* languishing somewhere on this site and you can post your solution as an answer on that questions page.

Comment: As @AlaskaMan said, this isn't a question, and doesn't work in our Q&A format.  And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) again so you'll know how best to participate here.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it isn't actually a question.

Comment: My bad.  I thought of reviewing the "rules", but got lazy.  I was just trying to share information since this gets asked a lot on the internet.  I like the idea of looking for an unanswered question. 
 Otherwise, I can find another forum for things like this.  Thanks.